# Proftpd - Disable AllowFilter on sub-folders

Tags: ftp, filter, proftpd

I'm trying to set up my ftp server properly, but I have a problem with the **[AllowFilter](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_AllowFilter.html)**.

***The Description:***

I want to restrict all commands by default and only allow a few. That works.
However. As you can see in my config I want to restrict all commands, just allow

```
LIST CDUP CWD XCWD XCUP MKD RETR RMD PWD MLS
```

*without the AllowFilter* 
and

```
STOR STOU RNFR RNTO DELE
```

*with the AllowFilter*

---

That all works fine, but here comes the strange part.

***The Problem:***

If I try to rename a directory, the Operation is not permitted, because I'm using the AllowFilter with "RNFR RNTO" to prevent other file extensions. I only want to allow .zip and .rar files.

**My question:** How can I **disable** the RNTO and RNFR command only on folders.

The filter is working fine for files (you cannot rename test.zip to test.exe), but I dont want to enable it on folders.

```
<Directory />

    <Limit ALL>
        DenyAll
    </Limit>

    <Limit LIST CDUP CWD XCWD XCUP MKD RETR RMD PWD MLSD>
        AllowAll
    </Limit>

    <Limit STOR STOU RNFR RNTO DELE>
      Order deny, allow
      AllowFilter ^[a-zA-Z0-9-_].*\.(zip|rar)$
    </Limit>

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a mailing list entry from 2005.

The Proftpd developer says, that you need the mod_rename Module for Proftpd.

> "....but I don't see a way how to deny (with Filename forbidden or
>   something) an upload of file containing invalid characters in filename
>   not affecting directories."

Source: http://osdir.com/ml/network.proftpd.user/2005-01/msg00118.html

I'm checking out the mod_rename Module.

Module: http://www.castaglia.org/proftpd/modules/mod_rename.html

Regards,

Steven